# SUNKEN Value working erratically when set thru an Event

Tags: python, tkinter

When I hand code buttons and pass an instance of them everything works as expected, but I create them programatically, the relief=value its value works erratically.

```
from tkinter import *  

def eventHandler(event):  
    wg = event.widget  
    if str(wg) == '.':  
        pass  
    else:
        # Get the Widget's Attributes
        print('name:', wg, 'state:', wg['state'])
        # Set the Widget's Attributes.
        wg.configure(state = DISABLED, bg = '#B29700', fg = '#EFCC90',
                        relief = SUNKEN)
        print('name:', wg, '| relief:', wg['relief'],'| state:', wg['state'])

win = Tk()
win.configure(bg = 'black')
win.geometry('200x200+500+50')
lb_Header = Label(win, text = 'Testing', fg = 'red', bg = 'black',
                        font = ('Arial Bold',20), pady = 5)
lb_Header.pack()

alpha = ['a', 'b']
for n in range(0,2):
    btn = Button(win, text = alpha[n], font = ('Arial Bold', 14), bg = 'gold',
                 fg = 'black', width = 2)
    btn.pack()

win.bind("<Button-1>", eventHandler)
win.mainloop()
```

In this version, if the same button is clicked  twice, the first time the button doesn't look sunken, although it reports to be 'sunken.' When clicked a second time, it reports to be sunken again and it also looks it.
However if you modify this section of the handler:

```
        # Set the Widget's Attributes.
        if wg['state'] == 'disabled':
            wg.bell()
        else:
            wg.configure(state = DISABLED, bg = '#B29700', fg = '#EFCC90',
                            relief = SUNKEN)
            print('name:', wg, '| relief:', wg['relief'],'| state:', wg['state'])
```

you will notice that when the button is clicked a second time, not only it doesn't look sunken, but it also reports relief: raised.

Since many times I have to create widgets programmatically - not only because is more convenient, but also because the number of them may vary - I need to access the widget's attributes through an event.
Does anyone know why does the aforementioned unexpected result happen and how I can solve this erratic behavior?

Comment: You should bind `<ButtonRelease-1>` instead of `<Button-1>`.

Comment: The indentation of your code example needs fixing.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley thanks for letting me know about the indentation oversight. In my module was fine, the problem was adding it to the post, which I just fixed.

Comment: @acw1668 - Thank you much! Your answer worked like a charm! Do you know the reason why the attribute works on release and not on click?

Comment: I looked in the help section, but I couldn't find the answer to: How can I set this post to answered, since it doesn't have check mark beside the answer?

Comment: If using `<Button-1>`, the callback will be called when the mouse button is being pressed.  You change the state of the button during the mouse button is being pressed.  When you release the mouse button, the button will be resumed to raised state.  I hope you can understand what I say as English is not my mother language.